# ArrayList 'squash' operation on its elements

Tags: java, loops, iterator, concurrentmodification

I have a problem that seems to be trivial but I'm looking for the best way of resolving that issue.

Let's say I have a class:

Product.class

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String code;
    private String price;
    private String quantity;

    public Product() {}

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (obj instanceof ProductOnStockDto) {
            ProductOnStockDto product = (ProductOnStockDto) obj;
            result = (this.code.equals(product.getCode()) && this.price.equals(product.getPrice()));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And let's say I have a list of this objects:

```
List<Product> products;
```

Which is filled with data like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqmjb.png)(1 row is one list element):

And what I need is to iterate over this list and squash elements that have the same code and the same price. For example:

In the result list I would like to have two products for `code 3`:

```
code 3 | 1.22 | 11
code 3 | 2.20 | 6
```

So I would do sth like this:

```
for(Product product : products) {
    for(Product productToSquash : products) {
        if(product.getId() != productToSquash.getId() && product.equals(productToSquash)) {
            //Here I would like to squash these two rows
            //Data conversion is ommited
            product.setQuantity(product.getQuantity() + productToSquash.getQuantity());
            //after that I would like to remove productToSquash object from the collection
        }
    }
}
```

But as I know it is not allowed to modify collection that I'm iterating on. So what would be the best way to squash all product list according to the example?

Answer (score 1):

Load them to the HashMap to "squash" and then load from it to the new collection

```
    class Pair
    {
         String code;
         float price;
    }

    HashMap<Pair, Product> hashMap = new HashMap<Pair, Product>();
    List<Product> collection = new ArrayList<Product>(); //a new container for your values

    //for every Product in products
    //    if in hashMap there is no Product with code and price add it
    //    else resolve it (override? ignore? ...)

    for(Entry<Pair, Product> entry : hashMap.values()) {
        collection.add(entry.getValue());
    }
```

Notice that you have to decide how exactly will you be squashing elements

Comment: Can't do `new List`. Did you mean `new ArrayList`? --- Can't iterate `hashMap`. Did you mean `hashMap.entrySet()`? --- If you did, why not use `hashMap.values()`? --- You need to `clear()` the collection before adding the values back. --- Original order of values are lost.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thank you for your advices, this code is kind of pseudo but of course I should care about proper syntax - I'm not sure if I get *clear()* thing - can you please explain?

Comment: You said "for every Product in `collection`", which presumes some code initially filling the `collection` list, then iterating that list to build `hashMap`, and finally adding values back to `collection`. If you don't clear the list before adding "merged" products back, you'd end up with lots of duplicates, except the ones you "squashed".

Comment: Oh now I get it - no I mean **collection** object to be new collection for items from origin collection

Comment: Thank you. I did exactly according to the pseudocode

Comment: Glad to help you - if answer is appropriate for you request you can accept it - [read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `equals()` method refers to `ProductOnStockDto`. That should be `Product`.

To remove elements during iteration, use the `Iterator` directly, i.e. use an "old style" for-loop, and use a `Map<Product, Product>` to keep track of products previously seen. This requires that you also implement `hashCode()`:

```java
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return this.code.hashCode() * 37 + this.price.hashCode();
}
```

```java
Map<Product, Product> map = new HashMap<Product, Product>();
for (Iterator<Product> productIter = products.iterator(); productIter.hasNext(); ) {
    Product product = productIter.next();
    Product productToKeep = map.get(product);
    if (productToKeep == null)
        map.put(product, product);
    else {
        productToKeep.setQuantity(productToKeep.getQuantity() + product.getQuantity());
        productIter.remove();
    }
}
```

You shouldn't really be doing it this way, since the `equals()` method is returning `true` for objects that are not truly *equal*.

You should instead have a key class with just `code` and `price`, and the key class is one that needs to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`, not `Product`.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpfull. Finally I created additional key class for map